# How to set default value for datetime field in MS DBAccess to Null when user did not set the date

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am working on a small project excel+VBA+DBAccess. Need to save data from Excel to Access Database. One of the fields in database is dateCompleted datetime.

The requirement is for INSERT: if a user enters a Date Completed in excel the field dateCompleted in db is saved. Or, if Date Completed in excel is empty then nothing is saved in the date completed, db field must be Null. But, as it is now the value is set to "12:00:00AM"

For DB Access table design I tried to set default value for dateCompleted to "Null" or "=Null".

In VBA code when adding a new record I tried:

```
If (dateCompleted <> "") Then
   ![dateCompleted] = dateCompleted
Else
   ![dateCompleted] = ""
   '![dateCompleted] = Null
End If
```

OR

```
If (dateCompleted <> "") Then
   ![dateCompleted] = dateCompleted
End If
```

In both cases db field is set to 12:00:00AM.

Is there way to set access db field of datetime type to default value or explicit assignment to Null in VBA?

Comment: If you start with 12:00:00AM then that will be a valid time so you will never get null. Set it to 24:24:24AM or xx:xx:xx and test from there. But you need to set that value prior to that if() loop, like right at the start of the code…

Comment: @SolarMike. Sorry, I am not sure I understand. To set default value in db for dateCompleted to 24:24:24AM or in my code ![dateCompleted] = "24:24..."?

Answer (score 0):

Set it to *Null*:

```vb
If IsDate(dateCompleted) Then
   ![dateCompleted].Value = dateCompleted
Else
   ![dateCompleted].Value = Null
End If
```

If *Null* is not allowed, a date must be used:

```vb
   ![dateCompleted].Value = #00:00#
```

Comment: I tried both set to "" and Null, not working.

Comment: `""` will fail, _Null_ will work if the field is allowed to hold _Null_ which is the default.

Comment: Using ![dateCompleted].Value = #00:00# doesnt work, VBA editor automatically resets the value to ![dateCompleted].Value = #12:00:00 AM# once I click away. The db data field allows Null but, not setting the data field to a value sets it to 12:00:00 AM. I am coming from MS SQL Server. Setting field to nullable and default to Null is not working the same way in Access. I

Comment: #00:00# and #12:00:00 AM# are the same. If _I am coming from MS SQL Server_ means that the table is linked from SQL Server, the datatype is most likely _DateTime2_ which the ODBC driver changes to text. If so, either change to _DateTime_ or write _text_ values to the table.